# Contentful API throws runtime error in combination with nuxt and vite

Tags: nuxt.js, contentful, vite

I am trying to adapt the [Contentful with Nuxt tutorial](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/javascript/tutorials/integrate-contentful-with-vue-and-nuxt/) to use the [Nuxt Composition API](https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/) which hopefully soon will be part of Nuxt 3 and also using [nuxt-vite](https://vite.nuxtjs.org/).
The script part of my index.vue looks like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, useAsync, useContext } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';
import useContentful from '~/plugins/contentful';
import { IBlogPost, IPerson } from '~/types/generated/contentful';

const CTF_PERSON_ID = '15jwOBqpxqSAOy2eOO4S0m';
const CTF_BLOG_POST_TYPE_ID = 'blogPost';

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { env } = useContext();
    const { client } = useContentful(env);

    const person = useAsync(() => client.getEntry<IPerson>(CTF_PERSON_ID));
    const posts = useAsync(() => {
      return client.getEntries<IBlogPost>({
        content_type: CTF_BLOG_POST_TYPE_ID,
        order: '-sys.createdAt',
      });
    });
    return {
      person,
      posts,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

I rewrote the example code of the `createClient` code to also follow the composition API standard and it seems to work as I can see the request and response in the debugger. The problem comes when the response is processed by contentful:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (0 , _fastCopy.default) is not a function
> at wrapEntryCollection (entry.js:118)
> at Object.getEntries (create-contentful-api.js:243)
> at async Object.getEntry (create-contentful-api.js:200)

I am aware that I use some experimental features, but as the error happens within the contentful code, maybe something else causes the problem.